# How to make the following code to be of the correct type, expecting to automatically deduce the return value type of the function

Tags: typescript

Here, res is expected to be a `number`, but it is actually inferred to be `any`

```
function f<T>(f: (v: Partial<T>) => any): ReturnType<typeof f> {
  return f({})
}

const res = f<number>((v) => 0) // any
```

If I also treat the function as a generic, I can’t just specify `T`

```
function f<T, F extends (v: Partial<T>) => any>(f: F): ReturnType<F> {
  return f({})
}

const res = f<number>((v) => 0) // TS2558: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
```

Comment: It's really confusing that you have given all your functions the name `f`. Why is this? Is there a shortage of names? Meaningful names would help differentiate the 'wrapper' function (and perhaps the intent of the function) from the function passed in (which could be named meaningfully too). More importantly it would prevent one from shadowing the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass `<number>` to `f` in the second example:

```
function f<T, F extends (v: Partial<T>) => any>(f: F): ReturnType<F> {
    return f({})
}
  
const res = f((v) => 0) // res:number

const res2 = f((p:{x?:string}) => p.x) // res2:string
```